# How can I get MD5/digest authentication working for a different domain?

Tags: sharepoint, iis, digest-authentication

I have been asked to set up a SharePoint site (running under IIS7 on 2008 R2) on a server in domain B, so that people in domain A can log in to it using MD5/Digest authentication over HTTP. There is a trust relationship so that B trusts A, and this works for Kerberos authentication. We have set up reversible encryption for passwords and checked that domain B users can log in with Digest, but we can't get it so that domain A users (not in the same domain as the SharePoint server) can log in with MD5/Digest over http. We have also checked with WireShark that the browser seems to be behaving itself (it is the version of IE that comes with Server 2008 R2 - I think IE7 but I don't have that written down).

Could you please either tell me how to set this up properly, or provide a link to a Microsoft or other reasonably authoritative document that says that this can't be done?

(by the way, we are using SharePoint Foundation (free version))

I am editing in some more recent information in case other people hit this, and because I would like any further suggestions to add to this, not duplicate it.

1) I set up SharePoint on two servers and then changed the domain of one of them, leaving the application pool users in the original domain. After some mucking around (add DNS suffixes from the original domain, fiddle with AAMs) I found that I could authenticate with digest in both servers, authenticating users in the same domain as the server - I'm not sure if this is a recommended configuration but I thought it was an interesting experiment. So this looks like a Windows feature, not a SharePoint feature.

2) Guessing that, I changed my search terms and found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778868%28v=ws.10%29.aspx "The Web server must be a member of the same forest as the user accounts." I think my setup corresponds to different forests, so this looks a lot like a "this behaviour is by design" windows feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following cmd command suitable for SP2010:
stsadm -o setproperty -pn "peoplepicker -searchforests" -pv "forest:[currentDomainName],[Username],[Password];domain:[newTrustedDomainName],[Username],[Password]" -url "[YourSiteUrl]"
Make sure you have alternative access mapping if required.

In general trusted domian should not be a problem, however I am not sure for MD5...

Comment: I have tried variants of that, and searched on the web for this parameter. I can set the parameter and read it out again and - by the combination of setting this and using a two-way trust - I can get users on the other domain visible to the peoplepicker in SharePoint Central Admin Farm Administrator GUI, but the users in the other domain still can't log in with MD5/Digest. By shifting the SharePoint machine from one domain to the other I can check that it is the domain mismatch. FWIW when they try and log in as DOMAIN\username there are WDIGEST auth fails in the security log.